# Why isn't the output of this Sallen-Key bandpass filter made with transistors like the output of the op amp version?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, band-pass, sallen-key

I made a transistor Sallen-Key Butterworth bandpass filter using two filter sections for each high-pass and low-pass stage.  The output is different from the op amp version.

I know it is possible to make Sallen-Key filters using a transistor and I am guessing has to do with using transistors and not an op amp and most likely it has to with impedance.  Maybe it is not possible to combine filters together if transistors are used.

If I look up Sallen-Key filters made with transistors, it seems just to be just a single filter.  I see nowhere online where they are combined together, in either multiple low-pass, high-pass , or low-pass/ high-pass combined together to make a bandpass.

[image: sallen-key bandpass]

Comment: Impedance all around. The class-A arranged BJTs are not opamps. And what's with the collector resistors? (Here's [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PSvi.png) from Don Lancaster's *Active Filter Cookbook*, bottom of page 11.)

Comment: @periblepsis I am guessing you can get it working, if you figure out the impedances ?

Comment: You may want to scale the parts in the transistor filter by a factor of 10, i.e.,  multiply resistor values by 10, divide capacitor values by 10. This will cause less loading of the stages and you'll get slightly more ideal response at low frequencies. Also, as periblepsis states, get rid of the 1k collector resistor.

Comment: Yes. It was done back in the day. (1960's, as by the mid 1970's opamps mostly took over.) Just as a guess, try a BJT (NPN 2N2222) and make a low pass 2nd order using 10 k resistors (both) and 15.9 nF capacitors (both.) I would predict a cross-over at 1 kHz (down 6 dB there.) Use +15 V and -15V per Lancaster's diagram and pick a 1 k pull-down load resistor to the - rail. Tell me what you see.

Comment: Bear in mind that the AC test input used to perform the AC analysis has zero source impedance (almost.) A real stage like this driving the next one will have a source impedance that you must account for. Note there's only attenuation, no gain, as shown.

Answer (score 2):

> [why is] the output is different from the op amp version?

Op-amps inputs have very high impedance and draw very little current. As a result, their effect on a circuit can very often be ignored. Not so with BJTs. You must account for the loading effects of the BJTs in calculating the frequency responses of the RC filters.

Op-amp outputs have very low output impedance. While the emitter resistance of a BJT can be quite low, in your circuit you have both collector and emitter resistors. Thus the output impedance of each stage will be high enough that it also needs to be taken into account.

Next, there is a major problem with how the last two stages are biased. You have them biased by a +2.5V *through capacitors*. This does absolutely nothing for biasing. As a result, the waveforms out of these stages will be highly clipped.

> If I look up Sallen-Key filters made with transistors, it seems just to be just a single filter? I see no where online where they are combined together, in either multiple low-pass, high-pass , or low-pass/ high-pass combined together to make a bandpass.

In many automated filter designers, one chooses a filter type (Chebychev, Butterworth, Bessel etc.), a number of stages, frequency, bandwidth, (and possibly more parameters) and the designer spits out resistor and capacitor values for each stage. However, each stage is simply a low-order filter with its own parameters. A compound Chebychev filter is simply the composition of low-order filters with different frequencies. A Butterworth filter is simply the composition of low order filters with different frequencies, bandwidths, etc..  Thus, if one first finds the desired parameters, i.e. frequencies, bandwidths, etc. of the individual stages, one can find the appropriate resistor and capacitor values for an op-amp implementation, OR for a BJT implementation (whose appropriate resistor and capacitor values will likely be different). So, the first step is to break the compound filter type (Butterworth etc.) into appropriate frequency - bandwidth components. Then you can apply the formulae used to create BJT Sallen-Key filters for each stage.

Comment: How do you figure out the component values for the BJT implementation? I know the same formulas are used , but impedance has to be included in the calculations?

Comment: That isn't the problem with the DC biasing. The last two stages get their bias from the second stage via the input resistors (albeit with a 0.7V drop per stage). It is not necessary for the capacitors to connect to the 2.5V supply normally they would connect to ground. The collector resistors should not be there as they will drop the collector voltage so that the transistors are probably in saturation

Comment: @KevinWhite Ah,  you are right. The last stages are DC coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Question: *How do you figure out the component values for the BJT implementation? I know the same formulas are used , but impedance has to be included in the calculations?*

Exactly THIS is the reason for opamp-based filter circuits. It is the goal of the filter designer (and the user !) to have formulas and design equations as simple as possible for realizing the desired filter parameters (pole frequency, quality figures, damping and gain properties).

Of course, a symbolic simulation program is able to find the transfer function of transistor-based filter circuits - however, this function must be in a form which allows extraction of the mentioned filter parameters. More than that, the corresponding formulas will be rather involved - and it will certainly not be possible to select the various filter parameters independently from each other.

As you can see - a lot of problems when using transistors with its dynamic small-signal input and output characteristics.

The situation will be even worse when you try to realize a cascade of several stages (as is the classical design strategy for opamp-based filter stages). Due to the finite input/output impedances a simple chain of several stages - individually designed - is also not possible.

**Comment**: R.P.Sallen and E.L.Key  published a paper in 1955 (only a few years after the BJT was introduced) with the title: "A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters". In this aricle the authors explain the working principle of various filter circuits which we call today "Sallen-Key-Filter". Interestingly, the shown and proposed filter stages are based already on the assumption of IDEAL voltage amplifiers (infinite input and zero output resistances) - although fully integrated opamp units were NOT yet available at this time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why it is difficult to find multi-stage BJT active filters based upon the class-A, single-BJT emitter follower topology; largely, just as you suggested: *Output impedance.* I agreed in my first comment to you.

This single BJT stage is able to rapidly follow the signal upwards, as the BJT emitter will follow the base upward with very low impedance. But it does ***not*** follow a downward going signal well, because the only thing pulling down is the emitter resistor. So part of the cycle is low-impedance and the rest of it carries the same impedance (almost) as the emitter resistor.

At higher frequencies (assume a low-pass filter, for now), the feedback capacitor will have very low impedance that the emitter resistor can't adequately drive. So it fails.

It's easy to show, without getting into the math. I'll just cobble up the single amplifier stage I suggested in comments:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcmIu4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's what LTspice says:

[image]

Note that is down slightly more than an expected \$-6.02\:\text{dB}\$ at \$1\:\text{kHz}\$. But at \$1\:\text{kHz}\$, \$C_1\$ is already about \$X_{_\text{C}}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, which is starting to load down \$R_3\$. As the frequency increases \$C_1\$ only presents an ever-increasing load on \$R_3\$ and this fact shows up in the slope and dip around \$65\:\text{kHz}\$.

What if we buffered the emitter? I can add an opamp follower as a buffer to drive \$C_1\$ (2-quadrant drive is a good thing) and see what happens:

[image]

Much better! So the output impedance of the BJT stage ***does*** matter.

So what's the point of the BJT now? No point. Let's remove it, entirely, and just use the opamp:

[image]

Very similar.

Of course, if you now ***add*** a 2nd stage this will only further load down the 1st stage, which is already struggling. There's also difficulties related to DC biasing, if AC coupling capacitors are not used. And with frequency-dependencies if AC coupling capacitors are used. Plus details of part variations and probably the need for high enough gain so that global closed-loop NFB can properly set the final gain of the overall system.

There's many fewer difficulties with the long-tailed pair, especially in conjunction with a current mirror load and an added VAS and output stage. But... well... now you have built a discrete opamp! Just build those as modules and use them as opamps, then.

Higher order filters are already difficult enough, given variations in part values -- especially capacitor variations. Some designs are less sensitive than others. But even saying that, there's no bright line. For example, a Sallen-Key generally is worse with respect to part variations than a multi-feedback. Except that with certain frequencies the multi-feedback requires rather much larger capacitor values than the Sallen-Key would. So everything depends upon... well, upon everything. There's no universal saws-all. You always have to think.

I also haven't seen 4th or 6th order filters done entirely with this kind of emitter follower stage. The difficulties associated with part variations, now including variations of the BJTs as well, is probably a large part of why.

But if what you are driving has a high enough impedance input, your frequencies sufficiently pedestrian, and all you have laying around is a BJT or two, then have at it. A 2nd order may perform (up to a point.)

Higher order filters built on this stage would be an academic exercise, perhaps as a tour-de-force to show how accurate modeling may be given sufficient effort. Might make an interesting paper. But otherwise? Not so much.